# Include fragment in a Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, menu, fragment

I'm making an app and I want to include fragments in the sample Navigation Drawer Activity from Android. By default it generates me a activity_main layout who includes an app_bar_main layout with the:

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And inside the app_bar_main activity includes me another layout in the `include`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UI.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

The problem occur when I put my `Fragment` in the include:

```
    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

Replaced by:

```
    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.urbandictionary.SearchFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I thought this should work but it breaks when it enters to the MainActivty:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

The error seems that is trying to add something in the `main thread` to a some `List`:

```
    public void registerOnActivityPausedListener(Activity activity,
        OnActivityPausedListener listener) {
    synchronized (mOnPauseListeners) {
        ArrayList<OnActivityPausedListener> list = mOnPauseListeners.get(activity);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<OnActivityPausedListener>();
            mOnPauseListeners.put(activity, list);
        }
        list.add(listener);
    }
}
```

And breaks when it made the `list.add(listener)`

Logs:

> 2019-06-14 11:39:52.350 15257-15257/com.example.urbandictionary E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.urbandictionary, PID: 15257
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.urbandictionary/com.example.urbandictionary.UI.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class fragment
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class fragment
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class fragment
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.urbandictionary.UI.MainActivity@83a791c must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
>           at com.example.urbandictionary.SearchFragment.onAttach(SearchFragment.kt:58)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1404)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1684)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1930)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3745)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:387)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.example.urbandictionary.UI.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:21)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: what is issue,you are facing?

Comment: @PrachiSingh sorry I update the question

Comment: post your Logs here

Comment: Fine, Logs posted!

Comment: according to Logs.. error is in your activity's xml on line number 12, and 26

Comment: The error seems to be when inflating Fragment, I made what I show in the code from above, so the problem should be there but I can find it. In my xml I have what comes from default in the sample, so mains layout is fine

Comment: if your xml is fine and the only error of main thread exception so try to put your code in runOnUiThread method. As i posted my answer below.

Comment: post your full xml here..in which you are getting issue